# Verification of Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I am very new to integrals. If someone would kindly take a look at them and confirm they are set up correctly that would be great!

---

> 1. D is the triangle with vertices $(0,0) (4,-2) (4,8)$ Evaluate $\int \int_D e^{x^2 +1}dA$

**My attempt**:

$\int_0^4 \int_0^{2x}  e^{x^2 +1}dydx$ + $\int_0^4 \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}x}  e^{x^2 +1}dydx$

$\approx 18116212.53$

---

> 2. D is the region where $x \geq 0$ bounded by $z = 4-x^2-y^2$ and xy plane. Evaluate $\int \int \int_D z+2dA$

**My attempt**:

$\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^2 \int_0^{4-r^2} (z+2)r dzdrd\theta$

$= \frac{40\pi}{3}$

---

Comment: You can check your answers with [WolframAlpha]( 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Be%5E%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C4%7D%2C+%7By%2C0%2C2*x%7D%5D%2BIntegrate%5Be%5E%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C4%7D%2C+%7By%2C0%2Cx%2F2%7D%5D)

Comment: HI, thanks! I was more wondering if I did the bounds correctly

Comment: Your set-up on the first intgeral will get you the correct answers.  But $1.8 \times 10^7$ is not correct.  However, there  is no reason to break up the integral into two.  $\int_0^4\int_{-\frac 12 x}^{2x} e^{x^2+1}\ dx$ is sufficient.

Comment: @Doug M Thank you! Do you mean "dydx" ?

Comment: Thanks, yes....

Answer (score 1):

I believe your second one is correct but your first integral should be set up like so:

$$\int_0^4 \int_{-.5x}^0 e^{x^2+1} dydx + \int_0^4 \int_{0}^{2x}  e^{x^2+1} dydx$$

$$\approx 30193687.5441$$

If someone else wants to verify....